# Create multiple columns from a single column and clean up results

Tags: r, split, tidyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
foo=data.frame(Point.Type = c("Zero Start","Zero Start", "Zero Start", "3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww","Zero Stop","Zero Start"),
               Point.Value = c(NA,NA,NA,rnorm(3),NA,NA))
```

I want to add three columns, by splitting the first column with separator `_`, and retain only the numeric values obtained after the split. For those rows where the first column doesn't contain any `_`, the three new columns should be `NA`. I got somewhat close using `separate`, but that's not enough:

```
> library(tidyr) 
> bar = separate(foo,Point.Type, c("rpm_nom", "GVF_nom", "p0in_nom"), sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right")
> bar
                            Point.Type    rpm_nom GVF_nom p0in_nom Point.Value
1                           Zero Start Zero Start    <NA>     <NA>          NA
2                           Zero Start Zero Start    <NA>     <NA>          NA
3                           Zero Start Zero Start    <NA>     <NA>          NA
4 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000rpm     10%   13barG   -1.468033
5 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000rpm     10%   13barG    1.280868
6 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000rpm     10%   13barG    0.270126
7                            Zero Stop  Zero Stop    <NA>     <NA>          NA
8                           Zero Start Zero Start    <NA>     <NA>          NA
```

I'm not sure why my data frame contains now two apparently different kinds of `NA`, but `is.na` seems to like them both, so I can live with that. However, I have two kind of problems:

1. the new columns should be at least `numeric`, and possibly `integer`. Instead they're `character`, because of the trailing `rpm`, `%`, `barG`. How do I get rid of those?
2. when `Point.Type` can't be split, `rpm_nom` should be `NA`, instead it becomes `Zero Start` or `Zero Stop`. Changing the `fill=` option only changes which one of the new columns get the `Zero Start`/`Zero Stop`. Instead I want all three of them to be `NA`. How can I do that?

NOTE: I'm using `tidyr`, but of course you don't need to, if you think there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post-process the columns with *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- foo %>%
  separate(Point.Type, c("rpm_nom", "GVF_nom", "p0in_nom"), 
           sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))), rpm_nom, GVF_nom, p0in_nom)
```

The `gsub("[^0-9]","",.)`-part removes all non-numeric characters. If you want to prevent the removal of decimal points, you *can* use `[^0-9.]` instead of `[^0-9]` (like @PierreLafortune used in his answer), but be aware that this will also include points that are not meant to be decimal points. By wrapping it in `as.numeric`, you convert them to numeric values while at the same time transforming the empty cells to `NA`. This gives the following result:

```
> foo
                            Point.Type rpm_nom GVF_nom p0in_nom Point.Value
1                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
2                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
3                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
4 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13  -1.2361145
5 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13  -0.8727960
6 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13   0.9685555
7                            Zero Stop      NA      NA       NA          NA
8                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
```

---

Or using *data.table* (as contributed by @DavidArenburg in the comments):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)[, c("rpm_nom","GVF_nom","p0in_nom") := 
             lapply(tstrsplit(Point.Type, "_", fixed = TRUE)[1:3],
                    function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",x)))
           ]
```

will give a similar result:

```
> foo
                             Point.Type Point.Value rpm_nom GVF_nom p0in_nom
1:                           Zero Start          NA      NA      NA       NA
2:                           Zero Start          NA      NA      NA       NA
3:                           Zero Start          NA      NA      NA       NA
4: 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww -0.09255445    3000      10       13
5: 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww  1.18581340    3000      10       13
6: 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww  2.14475950    3000      10       13
7:                            Zero Stop          NA      NA      NA       NA
8:                           Zero Start          NA      NA      NA       NA
```

The advantage of this is that `foo` is updated by reference. As this is faster and more memory efficient, this is especially valuable for using with large datasets.

Comment: @Jaap sounds great! Is it possible to avoid creating `bar`, by using `%>%`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg your solution also looks nice,  but what's a `data.table`? All my code works on data.frames. I'm worried that switching to these data tables might impact the rest of my code. Also, I don't know about function `tstrsplit`, but I guess that's documented in the `data.table`package.

Comment: @DeltaIV Updated the answer. A `data.table` is an enhanced form of a `data.frame`. See [this webpage](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) for more info.

Comment: Interesting! My dataframe is not really huge, but is much bigger than the example (it's more or less 2000 rows by 1200 columns). Maybe data tables would be good: I'll look into them. I'm a bit sorry to abandon Hadley Wickham's packages, since I loved them, but if the performance gain is substantial, it may be worth it!

Comment: Btw, instead of `as.numeric`, you could use `type.convert`, that way it will convert to `integers` and `numeric` correctly by itself.

Answer (score 1):

With `base R` we can first coerce `NA` values where necessary and coerce class `numeric`:

```
bar[-1] <- lapply(bar[-1], function(x) {
  is.na(x) <- grepl("Zero", x)
  as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x))})
#                             Point.Type rpm_nom GVF_nom p0in_nom Point.Value
# 1                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
# 2                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
# 3                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
# 4 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13   0.3558397
# 5 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13   1.1454829
# 6 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_ss_Pww    3000      10       13   0.2958815
# 7                            Zero Stop      NA      NA       NA          NA
# 8                           Zero Start      NA      NA       NA          NA
```

To reduce to one line (@Jaap):

```
bar[-1] <- lapply(bar[-1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `bar[-1]`. Also, what's the difference between @Jaap `gsub("[^0-9]","",x)` and your `gsub("[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", x)`? Finally, why in your last column you get `Point.Value`s of the order of 10^14? `rnorm(3)` should produce numbers much closer to 0.

Comment: `bar[-1]` removes the first column that we do not want to manipulate. The difference between the two regex patterns can be seen here http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/. In the final column the decimal was removed.