# Create multiple columns *of different format* from a single column and clean up results

Tags: r, split, dplyr

As maybe suggested by the title, this question is a follow-up to this similarly titled [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202797/create-multiple-columns-from-a-single-column-and-clean-up-results/35203389#35203389). There I asked how to split a character column of a dataframe in multiple numeric columns, using the separator `_`, and clean up results. In that case, all the columns were numeric, and they were created from following elements of the split columns, so the solution was easier. This time, things are a bit different:

```
foo <- data.frame(Point.Type = c("Zero Start","Zero Start", "Zero Start", "3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_R_Pww","Zero Stop","Zero Start"),
               Point.Value = c(NA,NA,NA,rnorm(3),NA,NA))
```

From column `Point.Type`, I need to create four columns, `rpm`, `GVF`, `p0` and `Setup`.

- `rpm`, `GVF`, `p0` must be of type `numeric` or `integer`, while `Setup`must be of type `character`.
- All the four new columns must be set to `NA` if `Point.Type` doesn't contain a `_` (rows 1,2,3,7,8 in my example).
- if `Point.Type`  does contain a `_` , then `rpm`, `GVF`, `p0` must contain the first three elements of `Point.Type`, "cleaned up" from all nonnumeric characters. `Setup` must be equal to `Full` if the 6th element of `Point.Type` is equal to `F`, otherwise it must be equal to `Reduced`. In my example, this means that `Setup` should be equal to `Full` for rows 4 and 5, to `Reduced` for row  6.

To get the  three `numeric` columns, I use the excellent solution from @Procrastinatus_Maximus , slightly reworded here:

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- foo %>%
  separate(Point.Type, c("rpm", "GVF", "p0"), 
           sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))), rpm, GVF, p0)
```

Now, the problem is the `character` column, `Setup`. Just naively writing

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- foo %>%
  separate(Point.Type, c("rpm", "GVF", "p0","Setup"), 
           sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))), rpm, GVF, p0,Setup)
```

won't work, because the value of `Setup` is not related to the element of `Point.Type` immediately after `p0`. Also, the value of `Setup` depends on whether the 6th element of `Point.Type` is `F` or `R`, but these are `character` values and they are just swept away from `mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))),...`. I got somewhere with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- foo %>%
  separate(Point.Type, c("rpm", "GVF", "p0"), 
           sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))), rpm, GVF, p0) 
library(stringr)
foo$Setup <- ifelse(str_split_fixed(setup$Point.Type,"_",7)[,6]=="F",
                                 "Full","Reduced")
```

which gives me

```
                           Point.Type  rpm GVF p0 Point.Value   Setup
1                          Zero Start   NA  NA NA          NA Reduced
2                          Zero Start   NA  NA NA          NA Reduced
3                          Zero Start   NA  NA NA          NA Reduced
4 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww 3000  10 13   1.9188554    Full
5 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww 3000  10 13  -0.5743683    Full
6 3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_R_Pww 3000  10 13  -0.7122796 Reduced
7                           Zero Stop   NA  NA NA          NA Reduced
8                          Zero Start   NA  NA NA          NA Reduced
```

However, as you can see it doesn't still work: `Setup` is equal to `Reduced` also in those cases where it should be equal to `NA`. Also, frankly I don't like the idea of loading `stringr` just for the sake of creating `Setup`. I'd much prefer to do all the job in `dplyr`, preferably in a single line of code using pipes. If that leads to unreadable code, then two successive calls to `dplyr` would also be ok.

Comment: I don't really see how this question would be "too broad", while the preceding one (of which this is only an hopefully simple extension) wasn't too broad at all. Why asking to manage just one more column would make the question too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I think this what you are asking for. I took you last example and added a mutate at the end of the chain.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo <- data.frame(Point.Type = c("Zero Start","Zero Start", "Zero Start", "3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_F_Pww","3000rpm_10%_13barG_Sdsdsa_1.0_R_Pww","Zero Stop","Zero Start"),
                  Point.Value = c(NA,NA,NA,rnorm(3),NA,NA))

res <- foo %>%
  separate(Point.Type, c("rpm", "GVF", "p0"), 
           sep="_", remove = FALSE, extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",.))), rpm, GVF, p0) %>%
  mutate(Setup = ifelse(!is.na(rpm), ifelse(grepl("_F_", Point.Type),"Full", "Reduced"),NA))
```

Comment: It works! I don't understand why the `NA` in the `Setup` look different from those in the other three columns (R prints them to screen as `<NA>` instead than `NA`). However, R seems to handle them just fine, so that's ok for me.

Comment: @DeltaIV The reason it shows up as <NA> is to distinguish it from a character entry that is NA, like the abbreviation for North America. In a single vector text shows up quoted, in a data frame it doesn't show up quoted, so NA's get < > around them.

Comment: Ok, so, the `NA` in the `numeric` columns (`rpm`, `GVF`, `p0`) don't get the <> because they are numeric, so there's no confounding with the string  `"NA"`. While in the `Setup` column, which is `character`, R adds <> to distinguish them from said string. Understood. Thanks!